# Used relative file path to link CSS, but file doesn't load and gives an error (MIME type not supported and strict MIME checking is enabled)

Tags: css, mime-types, relative-path, liveserver

I have linked my `CSS` file in `toDo.html` like this: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../reset.css">`.
This is what the directory looks like:

```
Web Dev
    |
     - reset.css
     - To Do List (folder)
          |
           - Folder1
                 |
                  - toDo.html
```

But the stylesheet doesn't load. Instead this error is displayed in console:

> Refused to apply style from 'http‍://127.0.0.1:5500/reset.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

All other files present in `Folder1` load without any error.

Note: This error is present only when the web page is opened using `Live Server` extension of VS Code. No error otherwise.